# Unable to view bucket from Account A in Account B using bucket policy for IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket in my `Primary Account`. I have added a bucket policy for this account to give access to an IAM user created by `Secondary Account` as below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<secondary-account>:user/maddy"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::input-read",
                "arn:aws:s3:::input-read/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, I logged in as a root user in the Secondary Account and added an inline policy for my IAM user as below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessToS3Bucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::input-read",
                "arn:aws:s3:::input-read/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I log in to my Secondary Account's IAM User via Console, I can't see this bucket. I followed multiple links like [this](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3) to check my approach and it looks correct to me.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You won't be able to see the bucket in the S3 console's list of buckets, if that's what you're hoping for. It only shows buckets in the current AWS account and it shows all, or none, depending on your ListBuckets permissions, regardless of any fine-grained IAM permissions or bucket policies. You cannot get the S3 console to list "all the buckets I have access to, across all AWS accounts".

Comment: BTW all of the actions in your policies are object-level so the resource `arn:aws:s3:::input-read`, which is bucket-level, is superfluous.

Comment: Yes I tried this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html and it worked but since `resource level policy` is available for s3, I want to see the bucket and underlying objects in my secondary account's IAM user console. So what exactly has to be done? @jarmod

Comment: If I can't access the bucket in my secondary account's IAM user then what is the exact use of that bucket policy? Where can I see the contents?

Comment: You can get/put/put-acl for the objects in the bucket but you have no permissions to list anything in this bucket or other buckets and you have no permissions to list buckets either, so I'm not quite sure how you think this would work. This user would need s3:ListBucket on arn:aws:s3:::input-read and would also need to explicitly fetch the URL e.g. https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/input-read (you need to fetch this manually because it's in a different account).

Comment: I have used `s3:*` since it is not a production account so for test purposes I used * and still I wasn't able to get the bucket but I wasn't sure that I needed a URL for the bucket. Again this is not mentioned in the docs I referred to.

Comment: You aren't going to see account B's bucket listed in the S3 console for an IAM user in account A. That doesn't mean you can't use the S3 console to list the objects in account B's bucket, however, as long as you have ListBucket permission. But to see the list of objects you will have to manually force your browser to fetch the correct URL, per above. The S3 console is simply not designed to list buckets that you might have access to in arbitrary AWS accounts.

Comment: Cool. Now I understood it completely. Thanks @jarmod. I will most probably go ahead with the `assume role` approach only. Since I have other services to provide and obtain. You can post your comment as an answer. I will accept it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you aren't going to see account B's S3 bucket listed in the S3 console for an IAM user in account A. The S3 console only lists buckets that exist in the same account that the logged-in IAM principal is a member of. The S3 console is not designed to list buckets that you might have access to in arbitrary AWS accounts.

That doesn't mean you can't use the S3 console to list the objects in account B's bucket, however, as long as you have s3:ListBucket permission. But to see the list of objects you will have to manually force your browser to fetch the correct URL, for example:

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/input-read
```

It's often better to simply create an IAM role in account B and [allow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html) the IAM user in account A to assume that cross-account role. You can then make cross-account access in the AWS console simpler using the [Switching to a role (console)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html) feature. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfE2G-fsBNU) showing this in action.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is for *cross-account access to objects*, what you are describing is being able *list* buckets cross-account.  You should be able to accomplish this by adding **s3:ListBucket** to both your S3 policy and your IAM access policy.

Here is the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) to the AWS S3 Actions, resources, and condition keys, its possible you may need another *list* permission.